# Cannot Moq a function in class X with an Action<X> parameter

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, delegates, moq

Apologies for the confusing title -- if there's a better way of wording this, I don't know what it is!

Anyway, I have a class setup like this:

```
public partial class Foo: IFoo
{
  ...
  public IFoo Do(Action<IFoo> action)
  {
    ...
    action(this);
    ...
    return this;
  }
}
```

The intended usage of this is to provide convenient access to a 3rd-party class, including try/catch blocks and allowing chaining.

Typical usage might look something like:

```
string s1 = null;
bool b1 = false;
fooFactory.OpenFoo(someParameter)
  .Do(f => s1 = f.FooFunction().AnArbitraryFunction())
  .Do(f => b1 = f.AnotherFooFunction(s1))
  .Close()
```

However, my attempts to Moq this have all resulted in failure. My current effort, in fact, throws the Test Runner out of the debug mode when it hits it:

```
public static Mock<IFoo> MockFoo()
{            
    var foo= new Mock<IFoo>();
    foo.Setup(m => m.Do(It.IsAny<Action<IFoo>>()))
        .Callback<Action<IFoo>>(a => a(foo.Object));
    return client;
}
```

The stack trace from the test runner gives an unhelpful System.NullReferenceException and, in the example above, the variables s1 and b1 are not assigned.

The intention here is that `MockFoo` passes on the `Action` in the `Do()` to be executed by the `MockFoo.Object`, so that any `IFoo` methods invoked can be mocked as per normal.

Any advice is welcome!

EDIT: as per  @HuorSwords' suggestion, the issue was the callback not returning anything.

The correct implementation is: public static Mock MockFoo()

```
{            
    var foo= new Mock<IFoo>();
    foo.Setup(m => m.Do(It.IsAny<Action<IFoo>>()))
        .Callback<Action<IFoo>>(a => a(foo.Object))
        .Returns(client.Object); // D'oh!
    return client;
}
```

Comment: It is possible that I am completely wrong, but... Have you tried to define `Return()` behavior on your mocked object? If it is throwing `NullReferenceException`, I think that will be because the `CallBack()` function is calling the `Action<IFoo>` parameter, but it is not returning anything...

Comment: Ha, thanks. I just had to add  `.Returns(client.Object)`.

As usual with these things, the actual problem is not what I thought it was and I just spent ages focusing on the wrong bit :)

Comment: I suggest you that answer your question with the final solution instead of editing the OP. ;) I'm happy to be useful for you. :)

Comment: Exactly. The solution should not be edited into the question above. Instead you or @HuorSwords should write a full answer.